# Check if an object is present inside an array of object, if yes then remove it from the array else add it to the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json

I am creating an array of objects by modifying the original object and keeping only a few attributes inside the new object. I want to check if the object I selected is already present inside the array or not , If it is already present in the array then it should be removed from the array else It should be added to the array.

So far I have this piece of code and the object gets added again to the array even if it's already present.
The roleId for each obj is unique .

```
 const ParticipantList = {
            firstName: function(){
              console.log('Inside firstName')
            }, 
            lastName: function() {  
              console.log('Inside LastName');
            },
            role: function(){
              console.log('role')
            },
            roleId: function(){
              console.log('role id');
            }
          };

const handleCheckboxChange = (id,firstName,lastName,roleId,setParticipants) => {
            const p= Object.create(ParticipantList);
              p.firstName = firstName;
              p.lastName = lastName;
              p.role = id;
              p.roleId = roleId;
              

            setParticipants((currentParticipants) =>
             currentParticipants.includes( roleId)
               ? currentParticipants.filter((f) => f !== p.roleId)
               : [...currentParticipants, p.roleId]
           
               
           );    
             };
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the array function `filter` to get an array that exludes a potential item with the `roleId` of the new object you want to add, then you just add the new object.

```
const handleCheckboxChange = (id, firstName, lastName, roleId, setParticipants
  ) => {
    const p = Object.create(ParticipantList);
    p.firstName = firstName;
    p.lastName = lastName;
    p.role = id;
    p.roleId = roleId;

    setParticipants(prev => [...prev.filter(item => item.roleId !== roleId), p]);
  };
```

Comment: It is adding the new object but this code snippet is not removing the object from the array if it's already present @hellogoodnight

Comment: It is removing all the existing elements with the same roleId as your new object, which I interpret is your way of identifiying an object?

Comment: I want it to behave like a check uncheck functionality . If the obj is not present in arr , it should be added but if it's already present then it should be removed

Comment: What logic defines whether an object is already existing in the array? If I look at your code, it appears as you use roleId to see if the object is already existing.

Comment: And btw, can you show me the definitions for `currentParticipants` and `setParticipants`.

Comment: const [claimParticipants, setClaimParticipants] = useState([]); currentParticipants is taking in the value of claimPaticipants and setParticipants is setting the value as setClaimParticpants

Comment: And how do you decide if an item already exists in the list? Is it on roleId or some other property?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240132/discussion-between-minmin240-and-hellogoodnight).